# pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image obj) doesn't work in python 3.9.1

Tags: python, pygame

I was using python 3.8 and everything was ok, but when I updated my python to 3.9 I figured out that pygame.display.set_icon doesn't work :/ (No errors, No warnings)

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
scr = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
fps = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Caption Here!")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("pics\\img.png"))

fps.tick(60)
pygame.display.update()
```

the problem is solved. it required a smaller image as it's icon =)

Comment: Yes.  it required a smaller image as it's icon

Answer (score 1):

See [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> [...] Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the icon before the display mode is set.

Set the icon before `pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))`:

```py
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("pics\\img.png"))

scr = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
```

In addition, the size of the icon is limited:

> [...] You can pass any surface, but most systems want a smaller image around 32x32.

If the icon is not displayed, try a smaller icon.

---

In addition, you need to handle the events. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

At least you need to invoke `pygame.event.pump()`.

Answer (score 0):

Working on OS Ubuntu with Python 3.10.7 /Pygame 2.12.2 neither of the hints above helped. No window icon is shown, not even the default pygame icon is shown if no custom icon is set.

EDIT:
The used .png files (sizes 16*16 and 32*32) were in the folder of the code. Checking the loaded file with 'pygame.image.get_extended()' returned TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the png image has to be in the same file as the code, it's either that or your image is too big.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).